# Boot failure : No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!

Tags: boot, vmware-server

I've tried to install Ubuntu on a VMWare Virtual Machine, but it never gets past the 
bootloader :

```
ISOLINUX 4.01 debian-20100714 ETCD Copyright (C) 1994-2010 H. Peter Anvin et al
No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!
boot: _
```

I've also tried to burn this .iso image to a CD and go from therem but I got the same problem.

Some more details :

- VMWare Server 2.0.2 Build 203138 on Windows 2008 R2
- ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso image used (downloaded yesterday evening)

Comment: Remark : The 10.04 LTS .iso boots like a charm - so that issue seems to be related to 10.10 ...

Comment: Have you tried downloading the ISO again? Perhaps you have a corrupt ISO

Comment: Hello Reuben, yes - I've downloaded it again after my first tries failed. Same result !!! I've also downloaded the 10.04 LTS version and the Server version - both can be installed without a problem ...

Comment: I'm having this problem too but only on the amd64 version. The 32-bit version works fine.

Answer (score 32):

If you are able to use a USB stick as installation media, then rename the following:

- isolinux --> syslinux (this is a folder)
- isolinux.bin --> syslinux.bin
- isolinux.cfg --> syslinux.cfg

This worked for me.

Original source: [1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9870976&postcount=18), [2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9889784&postcount=19)

Comment: I'm not sure how USB flash drives are relevant to the question...

Comment: My iso already have an 'syslinux.cfg'. Do I replace it with 'isolinux.cfg'?

Comment: Same as cvsguimaraes for me. Folder was already called 'syslinux' and there is already a 'syslinux.cfg' present, but there's no 'bin' file for either. I tried making a Live USB using Lili and 12.10 64-bit.

Comment: Got this same error trying to install beta Ubuntu Studio 13.10 to a physical machine.  This fixed it! +1, Thanks.

Comment: use `isomaster` or `furiusisomount` to edit `.iso` file

Comment: renaming teh folder through GUI is not possible, I also have tried via terminal(rm), but I got the Read-only file system. So I tried to unmount the main folder without success. Isn't  a new question but I am cannot find step I should do to make the just mounted USB readble to make the changes to the name

Answer (score 14):

Two suggestions:

Suggestion 1:

If you are using a USB stick, make sure it is formatted as FAT16 (or just FAT), not  as FAT32.

Suggestion 2:

Try entering `mboot.c32 -c boot.cfg` at the "boot:" prompt.

([Source](http://www.ivanlam.info/blog/2011/11/04/vmware-vsphere-hypervisor-esxi-5-0-installation-no-default-or-ui-on-boot/))

Comment: I tried #2 and it didn't help: `Could not find kernel image: mboot.c32`.

Comment: Formatting as FAT16 solved the issue for me: http://superuser.com/questions/202160/how-do-i-format-my-8-gig-usb-drive-to-fat-fat16-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the Ubuntu image to a USB flash drive using Startup Disk Creator and had the same error during booting it.

Launching Partition Manager I saw that the partition is FAT32. I recalled that I didn't format the partition during image writing -- it already was FAT32 (perhaps from previous Windows installation).

So I deleted the partition using Parition Manager and rewrote the image (Parition Manager showed that the created partition is FAT32 too). It booted fine. I guess something was wrong with the format of the partition.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using YUMI with USB memory stick there are certain Ubuntu versions which ISOs are not added correctly - for example, 16.04.5 LTS versions is added OK but version 16.04.6 LTS ISO image results in the "No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!" error