# Trying to boot from usb

Tags: boot, usb, laptop, iso

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boot failure : No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30374/boot-failure-no-default-or-ui-configuration-directive-found)

I have similar issues but none with the 12.04 build.

Im trying this on a dell d610 laptop with a bad hard drive and was told i could just directly boot from the usb drive.

Im using an 8g usb drive and i have tried using the uui tool and get this message.
SYSLINUX 4.06 EDD 4.06-pre1 Copyright (c) 1994-2011 H.Peter Anvinet al
ERROR: No configuration file found
No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!

Then i tried using unetbootin and got the bootup screen with only the default option and it would say auto boot with a 10 sec countdown and start over again.

I do have the boot sequence for usb first.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On the USB key, rename the `isolinux` folder to `syslinux`.

In the same folder, rename the `isolinux.bin` and `isolinux.cfg` files to `syslinux.bin` and `syslinux.cfg`, respectively.

Now, try booting with the USB drive again.

Comment: I tried the name changes and got the same response.

Comment: Is the download a iso file cause i think mine is a zip but i got it from here.http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Is there any more specific instructions on how to do this.I want to use universal usb installer.

Comment: Thank you sircharlo i finally figured it out the sys prefix worked as you mentioned.The other issues were operator error.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it!! Seems like a bug in the USB creator software...

Comment: In my instance a `syslinux` folder already existed, so I simply renamed it to `syslinux_old` and then followed the above steps. Worked for me. =)

Comment: worked for me.  original usb was made from Startup Disk Creator in 13.04.

Comment: Admins are out of control with what they label as duplicates <shakes head>

Answer (score 2):

The root cause to this system error is FAT32.
I think your Bios cannot understand FAT32 file system. May be your system is old one. Format the USB with FAT16, or simply FAT file system and then create the usb bootable stick that will definitely work....

Comment: There is no such thing as "simply FAT" as distinct from FAT16 or FAT32 (or some of the other less common FAT filesystems like exFAT). FAT by itself, when intended to refer to a specific filesystem, typically refers to FAT16.

Answer (score 0):

Dell d610 boot fromusb should be fine, though mine is d620. Try yumi which I think is the best USB creator for Linux and other things. 
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

Comment: Did not try this method so i cant comment.But thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The USB drive partition type was NTFS. I re-ran the Universal USB installer and made sure to check the box to format the drive FAT32 and everything worked well after that.