# Error: No default or UI configuration directive found

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boot failure : No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30374/boot-failure-no-default-or-ui-configuration-directive-found)

I downloaded the new 12.04 file amd64 ISO. Burned it to a cd but having no luck. New Dell Inspiron 17R 64 bit with windows 7 home premium.  Set the computer to boot from the CD/DVD but it comes up with No Default or UI configuration directive found?  Burned two more disk but no lick with any of the three.   Any help appreciated.  thanks Matt

Comment: Can explain more the problem you have? How did you download the iso? Do you check the md5sum of the downloaded file? Did you check the cd?

Comment: This is good advice, although I can't find where Ubuntu publishes the md5sums anymore.

Comment: @Hemlock For anyone who still needs this information, see: [Where to find the md5sums of Ubuntu ISO images?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9417/where-to-find-the-md5sums-of-ubuntu-iso-images) (The *main* place to get MD5SUMs is [UbuntuHashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes). See also [HowToMD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM).)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with help from a good friend.  The Dell Inspiron 17R has a optional setting in the bios for the DVD/CD.  It is not set for the standard SATA drive option it was selected for some new power saving HVC (the abbreviation may not be correct) mode at boot up.  The Ubuntu disk would start up and work on loading up the operating system but the computer did not get feed back soon enough so it powers down the drive and the message pops up.  Went in the bios and changed it for just the load and set it back after the install.  Good to go no trouble with Ubuntu or windows 7.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On Dell Vostro, I had to change SATA Operation setting to ATA in BIOS to make the CD boot.
It is probably important to set it back after installation, because BIOS advices against changing it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to rename some files. I had the same issue and solved it with the accepted answer to another question here:
[Trying to boot from usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128160/trying-to-boot-from-usb)