# USB Ubuntu 12.4 boot problem

Tags: 12.04, usb, boot-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boot failure : No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30374/boot-failure-no-default-or-ui-configuration-directive-found)

Salam everyone.  I searched the entire forum but no solution worked for me.  I downloaded the ISO image of Ubuntu 12.4. and by using Unetbootin I made my USB drive bootable.

But on booting it gives error  "syslinux 3.86 2010-04-01 ebios copyright 1994-2010 H. Peter Anvin et al. no default or UI configuration diretive found. boot:"

I checked the md5sum  they are also fine.  I tried changing folder and file names to sys and formated my derive fat32 and fat but nothing worked.  I tried different boot programs like LiLo and linuxpenderive.

But Mr. Peter Anvin is not willing to leave my boot screen. so what should I do??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried a different USB drive?

Answer (score 0):

Aleikum Salam!

I give you 2 solutions:

1. Format the stick as FAT16 (or just FAT), not as FAT32.
2. Type: `mboot.c32 -c boot.cfg` at the `boot:` prompt.

Answer (score 0):

After eliminating MBR of a USB drive by the following command , and try reformatting in fat32 form (and add boot flag) by Gparted.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=512 count=1
```

**Caution:** /dev/sdx should replace to the device name of USB drive.