# No default or UI configuration directive found

Tags: configuration, default

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boot failure : No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30374/boot-failure-no-default-or-ui-configuration-directive-found)

I've basically got the same problem as everyone else getting this error *but* renaming the folders and files doesn't work because the folder and files has already gotten the names being suggested to switch to.

I am installing the OS from a USB-drive which I created using the LiLi USB Creator and I know it works because I've used it on another laptop and it worked perfectly.