# trouble with installing ubuntu 12.10 from usb

Tags: 12.10, boot, usb, amd-processor

I have recently built my own PC and I want to use Ubuntu as my OS, but when I try to boot Ubuntu up using my USB I get an error saying:

`no default UI configuration directive found`

I have tried to rename the OS Linux files, but that did not appear to work. (But I may have been doing it completely wrong.)

I'm running an AMD machine if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a thread that might help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30374/boot-failure-no-default-or-ui-configuration-directive-found). In addition to renaming the files, it mentions that formatting the USB key as FAT16, not as FAT32, might help. Some people complained that using Pendrivelinux installer caused some trouble.

Comment: Where does it say how to format as FAT16?

Comment: @user134791 [Mike said it in a comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30374/boot-failure-no-default-or-ui-configuration-directive-found#comment241753_119279).