# Ubuntu Freezes While Installing

Tags: freeze

I am trying to install ubuntu 12.04, but every time I get to the restart computer screen my computer freezes. Then when I try to restart my computer manually I get a black screen with a flashing -

Comment: is it in virtualbox or by itself?

Comment: No Jorge Castro because that article doesn't exactly answer my question.

Comment: have you tried the solutions in here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, caused by **UEFI** and laptop's specific problem.
Try to format your USB drive into **UTF-16**, and do other things like this: [maybe your situation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329704/syslinux-no-default-or-ui-configuration-directive-found)

But I solved my problem by installing 13.10, and then 12.04. (And then delete 13.10, I know that is bad resolution, but it work for me).