# How do I install Ubuntu via USB?

Tags: system-installation

I have laptop with 512MB ram and 80 GB HDD, dual core 2.0GB Hz speed, 32bit
earlier i was using W-XP on this once i have tried to install Win7 and it get all problematic. now have tried to install back Win-Xp but it get hanged in between and shows the message , file not found. hence decided to go for Ubuntu.

I Have already downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 ISO file. I want to know how to install it from USB and if the message of "file not found" reappears, then what to do.

Comment: Did the error message also tell you _which_ file it couldn't find?

Comment: Is is not clear if you are having trouble with creating a USB installer, or using it to install **Ubuntu**. *Ask a clearer question.*

Comment: I have the problem in installing Win-XP back on my Laptop, the massage appear is " window could not found the file".

Comment: Now i am planning to boot via Ubuntu, and hence, asking if the similar massage appear, then what to do. I will install it via and hope this will be done without any problem.

Comment: This is not the duplicate of the offered post because it doesn't explain installation from USB. Perhaps vipers36 solution work for you? If you have difficulties with 14.04 try Lubuntu. P.S. Since you haven't provided info about the file it is pointless to respond.

Comment: it says "system32/config/system"

Comment: It is the core of the Windows OS so it shouldn't cause any problem.

Comment: HI, I have followed the way you have guided for installing Ubuntu 14 but it not get installed, the boot shows following message. SYSLINUX 4.07 EDD 2013-07-25 COPYRIGHT (c) 1994-2014 H. Peter Anvin et al. ERROR: No configuration file found: no DEFAULT OR UI configuration directive found. please help in installation

Comment: Hm, very interesting. There is no way for me to reproduce that. Perhaps this [could help.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329704/syslinux-no-default-or-ui-configuration-directive-found)

Answer (score 0):

To install the ISO on a USB stick on ubuntu, you can use the startup disk creator as described [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).

On windows, you can use the USB installer provided at pendrivelinux.com.
You'll find the download [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Once you have the bootable USB stick, switch off your computer and insert the USB drive. If you switch on the computer, enter the BIOS menu and choose to boot from USB. You normally find a message when booting how to enter BIOS on your system. (Something like 'Press F12 to enter boot menu')

Comment: HI, I have followed the way you have guided for installing Ubuntu 14 but it not get installed, the boot shows following message. SYSLINUX 4.07 EDD 2013-07-25 COPYRIGHT (c) 1994-2014 H. Peter Anvin et al. ERROR: No configuration file found: no DEFAULT OR UI configuration directive found. please help in installation