# Error: No default or UI configuration found

Tags: system-installation

I know that this is probably a duplicate question, but since I'm a new user, I am unable to post on the other threads.

As a result, I'm forced to create another thread. On the thread below someone suggests formatting the USB in FAT 16 rather than FAT 32.

This is opposite everything else I've read (and besides it still didn't work for me).
[Boot failure : No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30374/boot-failure-no-default-or-ui-configuration-directive-found/119279#119279?newreg=c325b2b5acdc4e8aab586332f02114ce)

```
Error: No default or UI configuration found
```

Things I've read and tried:

- Downloading the iso several times to ensure I have a good iso
- Trying both 13.10 and 14.04 (both 32 & 64)
- Changing isolinux files to syslinux files
- copying syslinux file in to the boot file

Note: Wubi does work but only lets me partition up to 30GB and I want to have only one operating system.

All with the same problem.  Is there a solution to this?

I have an old AMD dual core 3800+ Gigabyte motherboard (GA M55SLI?), "2.9GiB memory" (according to Wubi) There is an Nvidia graphics card but I can't recall which one

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install with?

Comment: I've attempted both 13.10 and 14.04 (the current ones listed under "desktop" from ubuntu site

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to burn Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon on a USB drive which was formatted in FAT32, iso burned using UNetbootin on Ubuntu 14.04. I formatted the drive in ext4, burned the iso again with the same parameters and it worked fine.
I didn't have to rename or move files within the USB drive.

I read on some other forums that a FAT16 formatting should do the job too, but I didn't try.