# old Dell is giving me "No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!" when booting from usb

Tags: boot, usb, dell

I got Dell Inspiron 5150 and I cannot make wireless work under Windows XP so I thought I try linux - I got ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso image handy so I put in on my usb stick using Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.2.exe

Then I tried booing and got the **subject** message.

I tried everything that the other post [Boot failure : No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30374/boot-failure-no-default-or-ui-configuration-directive-found) suggested

1. Renaming

   isolinux --> syslinux (this is a folder)

   isolinux.bin --> syslinux.bin

   isolinux.cfg --> syslinux.cfg
2. formatting the stick as FAT/FAT16
3. Try entering mboot.c32 -c boot.cfg at the "boot:" prompt.
4. trying different usb sticks.
5. I tried to boot slax but it finished `Fatal error occurred - cant find executable chroot command` - I am going to try the latest version of slax now. **UPDATE** so the latest slax slax-English-US-7.0.8-i486.iso is giving me boot: /boot/vesamenu.c32: not a COM32R image. Hm the older slax went further in the boot process.... but it is overwritten now.
6. Puppy Slack linuxn - slacko-5.7.0-PAE.iso - gave me the same error `boot: /boot/vesamenu.c32: not a COM32R image`

Any help how to make Ubuntu work on this old Dell is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Go to BIOS settings and change the boot order to boot HD first and USB last. This happened to me awhile back and for some reason that fixed it for me.

Comment: How could it help? I need to use F12 and then select to boot from usb? Well let me try ...

Comment: The order in BIOS is different to the one after I press F12. After F12 the 1st always hdd and second usb. Your advice didn't help.