# No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!

Tags: boot, usb, error-handling

I am trying to run/install Ubuntu on my laptop (this runs on Win10 - upgrade from a Win7[Legacy BIOS]).
I have created a bootable Ubuntu USB. Each time I restart my laptop with the bootable USB I get the following: No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!

I have renamed 3 items as suggested in previous posts:  isolinux –> syslinux (folder) / isolinux.bin –> syslinux.bin / isolinux.cfg –> syslinux.cfg

I have also read that the USB will need to be formatted using FAT16 instead of FAT32.

But still no luck.

My questions are:
How do I format and create this bootable USB with FAT16 as the software I am using creates doesn't give me an option of FAT16 (am using Rufus).

Is there anything else I need to be doing/checking?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boot failure : No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30374/boot-failure-no-default-or-ui-configuration-directive-found)

Comment: Can you type `live` and hit Enter?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have managed. I was using a 8gb USB stick, then swapped it to a 2gb USB and used [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com). 
Didn't have to rename those 3 items.

I am now able to boot up Ubuntu and use the "Try Ubuntu" option.

Many thanks for your response and links to other answers.